# Closed set through continuity

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

I have the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}))$ and the set $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid w(x)\in[\theta, \eta], ||x||_2\in[r,R]\}$, where $0\le\theta\le\eta<2\pi, \text{and } 0< r\le R$. The function $w(x)$ is given by $\cos(w)=\frac{x_1}{||x||_2}\text{ and }\sin(w)=\frac{x_2}{||x||_2}$.

First I have to show that $A$ is closed. So I'm thinking of using the continuity of $w(x)$ and $||x||_2$ to show this, since the preimage of closed set is again closed. So for $||x||_2$ we simply have:

$f(x):=||x||_2=\sqrt{x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}}\rightarrow f^{-1}([r,R])=B,$ where $B$ is of course  a closed set.

on the other hand, I was told that $w(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(x_1,0),x_1\ge0\}$(but not everywhere?). So how can I go from this to
$w^{-1}([\theta,\eta])=C,$ where $C$ is closed. And ultimately, $A=B\cap C.$